# Spark's from_json returns null even if only 1 of the nested elements doesn't fit the schema

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a simplified DataFrame Row that contains a json string.
This json string contains nested elements.
I read this json string column using Spark's from_json(...) method, providing it a schema of the json string.

Let's say that this json string looks like this:

```
{
"key1_1": {
    "key2_1": "value2_1",
    "key2_2": "value2_2"
}}
```

And that the schema is declared as follows:

```
StructType schema = new StructType();
    schema = schema.add("key1_1", new StructType()
            .add("key2_1", DataTypes.StringType)
            .add("key2_2", new MapType(DataTypes.StringType, DataTypes.StringType, true))
    );
```

The json string data fits the schema's "key1_1", and "key2_1", but not "key2_2" because in the data the value of this key is of type string, and in the schema it's declared as a map.

I would like to get the values of "key1_1" and "key2_1", as they fit the schema, instead of getting null for the whole record, because of the nested "key2_2" value.
Is there a way I can get that result?

I thought of dividing the schema to separate small ones, but I wonder if I can achieve it with only 1 schema, as the schema I'm working on is pretty big and complex.

===============================================

Here's the whole code snippet:

```
package com.example.sparkproject;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static class RowData {
        private int id;
        private String jsonString;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getJsonString() {
            return jsonString;
        }

        public void setJsonString(String jsonString) {
            this.jsonString = jsonString;
        }

        public RowData(int id, String jsonString) {
            this.id = id;
            this.jsonString = jsonString;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argh) {

        StructType schema = new StructType();
        schema = schema.add("key1_1", new StructType()
                .add("key2_1", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("key2_2", new MapType(DataTypes.StringType, DataTypes.StringType, true))
        );

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local[1]")
                .appName("MyApp")
                .config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
                .getOrCreate();

        List<RowData> list = List.of(new RowData(1, "{" +
                        "\"key1_1\": {" +
                        "\"key2_1\":\"value2_1\"," +
                        "\"key2_2\":\"value2_2\"" +
                        "}" +
                        "}"));

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(list, RowData.class);

        df.select(functions.from_json(functions.col("jsonString"), schema)).show(false);
        df.select(functions.from_json(functions.col("jsonString"), schema)).printSchema();

    }

}
```

And the output of the code snippet above is:

```
+---------------------+
|from_json(jsonString)|
+---------------------+
|[]                   |
+---------------------+

root
 |-- from_json(jsonString): struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key1_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key2_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key2_2: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```